# What does this strange number mean in the output? Is this some memory Location?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stdlist

The node Class is as follow:

```
class node
{
    public:

    int data; //the datum
    node *next; //a pointer pointing to node data type
};
```

The PrintList Function is as follow:

```
void PrintList(node *n)
{   while (n != NULL)
    {
        cout << n->data << endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

If I try running it I get all three values (1,2,3) but I get an additional number as well which I'm unable to figure out what it represents, Can someone throw light on the same?

```
int main()
{

    node first, second, third;
    node *head = &first;
    node *tail = &third;
    first.data = 1;
    first.next = &second;
    second.data = 2;
    second.next = &third;
    third.data = 3;

    PrintList(head);    
}
```

I Know it can be fixed with

```
third.next = NULL;
```

But I am just curious what does this number represents in output, If I omit the above line

```
1
2
3
1963060099
```

Comment: `NULL` is a legacy C integer constant, and it is advised to use `nullptr` in C++ instead.
"I Know it can be fixed with" -> This is not a fix, this is the correct way to program.
You are trying to access an unitialized variable (`third.next` is never assigned), which is undefined behaviour

Comment: As you correctly noticed, `third.next` was not initialized to `NULL` before the fix. So `third.next` was derefenced, yielding to *undefined behavior*. The most probable behavior would be a segmentation fault, but here `third.next` happened to contain a memory address that was accessible and containing the number 1963060099.

Comment: One reason to invent C++ was to have the possibility to define automatic initialization for classes like `node`. That language facility is called "constructor" ;-). Exercise: What should `node`'s constructor do? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comment by prapin, `third.next` is not initialized.
C++ has a zero-overhead rule.
Automatically initializing a variable would violate this rule as the value might be initialized (a second time) later on or never even be used.

The value of `third.next` is just the data that happened to live in the same memory location as `third.next` does now.
For this reason, it's recommended to always initialize your variables yourself.

Comment: Perfect Explanation, Now I've understood it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to initialize variables & it is better to use `nullptr`. Like that (See 1-3):

```
#include <iostream>

class node
{
public:
    int data = 0; // 1
    node* next = nullptr; // 2
};

void PrintList(node* n)
{
    while (n != nullptr) // 3
    {
        std::cout << n->data << std::endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    node first, second, third;

    node* head = &first;
    node* tail = &third;

    first.data = 1;
    first.next = &second;

    second.data = 2;
    second.next = &third;

    third.data = 3;
    // third.next points to where?

    PrintList(head);
}
```

**Additional note:**

I would prefer to use the STL container `std::list`:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

std::list<int> int_list;

void PrintList()
{
    for (auto i : int_list)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int_list.push_back(1);
    int_list.push_back(2);
    int_list.push_back(3);

    PrintList();
}
```

Or in case of list of `node` objects:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class node
{
public:
    node(int data) : m_data{ data } {};
    int m_data = 0;
    // and maybe extra data-members
};

std::list<node> node_list;
 
void PrintList()
{
    for (auto i : node_list)
        std::cout << i.m_data << std::endl;
}   

int main()
{
    node_list.push_back(node(1));
    node_list.push_back(node(2));
    node_list.push_back(node(3));

    PrintList();
}
```

Comment: :) Thanks for the additional note, I was just trying my hands for the first time on linked lists